# Night's Dawn - P F Hamilton - Quinn Dextor's Possession

Tags: nights-dawn-trilogy

Just completed the trilogy and although I liked it, there were a few oddities. Maybe I am remembering it incorrectly but when Quinn Dextor left Lalonde on the Lady Mac he was still Quinn Dextor, although he seemed to have possessed talking to him. Marie Skibbow recognised him as Quinn in the bar before they left.

When he was in his bunk on the Lady Mac he was tormented by the possessed but he certainly hadn't been taken over by one.

The next time we see him torturing Grant on Norfolk, he is clearly possessed as he overcomes his possessor.

So, when did the possession happen?

Comment: Hi there. Just a thing - is there any chance you and the Dave who wrote [this answer](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/217384/98028) (on the same subject, a couple minutes ago) are the same person? If so, please consider merging the two accounts by following [these instructions](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: I'm not quite sure what your question is here, at the moment it just seems to be a bunch of related thoughts, could you [edit] this to explicitly state the question?

Comment: Another thing..  I never read those, so maybe it's just me not "getting" it, but I don't understand what your question is? Please [edit] to clarify. I won't vote to close as "unclear what you're asking" (since, again, it might come from my lack of knowledge about the work), but I'm imagining some others might

Comment: @Dave: I hope you don't mind, but I removed your last sentence, which was a direct request for an opinion, and added a sentence explicitly asking what you seemed to be working around in the prior paragraphs. I apologize if I misinterpreted your question in any way.

Answer (score 3):

Quinn is possessed on Lalonde, from memory he's the first human to be possessed.

***But***

Because he's stronger willed than the spirit that possesses him (also crazy, sadistic, and able, and cheerfully willing, to psychologically torture said spirit into submission) he maintains a larger degree of autonomy than most other possessed individuals who come later. He can use the abilities that come from possession without being wholly under the control of the spirit from beyond so he acts as if he weren't possessed much of the time while in fact he is.

All possessed hear the voices of other spirits from beyond trying to get back into the world and are variously effected by them.

Comment: He's definitely the first possessed.

Comment: @Jontia Thanks for the confirmation, it's been a while so I wasn't certain.